# Using Phoenix Miner - Noob Question

Tags: blockchain, wallets, wallet-transfer

I am using Phoenix Miner - Ran it for around 8 to 10 hours as a trial - I setup my Public Wallet ID as My wallet ID, I have yet to see anything pending into my account - I am wondering If I am missing something? It's been around 12 to 14 hours since I have ran it.

I am using Meta Mask as the wallet - from what I have heard this is good for short term for the funds to go into the account . I can upload my setup file later in case I am missing something as well but no errors the miner runs just fun I just haven't seen anything and do not want to continue until I get that sorted.

Thanks in advance for any help given .

Comment: Hi there. Unless you have some serious hashing power (or are part of a pool), you're unlikely to mine anything in that period of time. Plug some values into a mining calculator and check the average numbers of days it'll take you to find a block -> https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

Comment: Thank you - I am in a mining Pool not doing solo - No serious hashing power, I am at around 85 hashing power. I knew I wouldnt see much but I figured I would see some amount of money go into my address . Not sure if that would be a different case. Thank you again for your feedback!

Comment: Okay, the next thing to check would be whether your mining pool imposes any payout thresholds. It might be the case that they'll only pay out once <x> has been reached.